# How to run code using Node.js Fibers

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fibers

I have a question about Nodejs Fibers(which is absolute new for me) ...
I have this tutorial for Nodejs Fibers, http://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/fibers-and-threads-in-node-js-what-for/, and there was an example in here it says

```
    var fiber = Fiber.current;
    db.connect(function(err, conn) {
    if (err) return fiber.throwInto(err);
       fiber.run(conn);
    });
   // Next line will yield until fiber.throwInto 
   // or fiber.run are called
   var c = Fiber.yield();
   // If fiber.throwInto was called we don't reach this point 
   // because the previous line throws.
   // So we only get here if fiber.run was called and then 
   // c receives the conn value.
   doSomething(c);
   // Problem solved!
```

Now based on this Example I created my own version of the code like this,

```
  var Fiber = require('fibers');

  function sample(callback){
     callback("this callback");
  }

  var fiber = Fiber.current;
  sample(function(string){
     fiber.run(string);
  });
  var string = Fiber.yield();
  console.log(string);
```

but this gives me an Error of,

```
/home/ubuntu/Tasks/ServerFilteringV1/test.js:28
    fiber.run(string);
      ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'run' of undefined
```

And I have another case which will run a function after 1000 ms with the callback inside (I have done this to test functions with long time executions before a callback),

```
var Fiber = require('fibers');

function forEach(callback){
   setTimeout(function(){
       callback("this callback");
   },1000);
}


var fiber = Fiber.current;
forEach(function(string){
   fiber.run(string);
});
var string = Fiber.yield();
console.log(string);
```

This code in here gives me another Error ,

```
/home/ubuntu/Tasks/ServerFilteringV1/test.js:30
var string = Fiber.yield();
                    ^
Error: yield() called with no fiber running
```

Well, should the yield() wait after a run() function is executed? 
Any idea about what is happening in my nodejs code?
And thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Example 1

A fiber is a sort of lightweight thread of execution. Like real threads and processes, a fiber must be given a block of code to execute upon run. The code as you took it from *bjouhier* does not work as is. It was intended to run inside a fiber, like so:

```js
var f = Fiber(function() {
    var fiber = Fiber.current;

    sample(function(str) {
        fiber.run(string);
    });

    var str = Fiber.yield();
    console.log(str);
});

f.run();
```

Calling `run` on the fiber, well, runs the fiber code, which was given as callback to `Fiber`. The above code, however, will also give an error (stating the fiber is already running). One might easily see why when analysing the order of execution.

1. **Set** variable `f` as a fiber.
2. **Run** the fiber:

   1. **Set** variable `fiber` pointing to the current running fiber.
   2. **Call** function `sample`.
   3. **Call** the callback.
   4. **Call** `fiber.run`, which gives the error as the current fiber is already running.

The structure of this code is correct, but it assumes `sample` is some asynchronous function that does not immediately call the callback. Let's swap out your `sample` function by this one:

```
function sample(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback("this callback");
    }, 500);
}
```

Now, the above code won't emit an error, as `sample` immediately returns. The order of execution inside the fiber is:

1. **Set** `fiber` pointing to the current running fiber.
2. **Call** `sample`, which returns without calling the callback (yet).
3. **Call** `Fiber.yield(), which 'pauses' the current fiber.
4. After 500 ms, **call** the callback.
5. **Call** `fiber.run()` passing 'this callback', which resumes the fiber.
6. `Fiber.yield` returns, **Set** str to 'this callback'.
7. **Log** the string to console.

Observe that step 4 is done outside the execution of the fiber.

### Example 2

Whereas in the first example there was no running fiber (and therefore `fiber` was **undefined**), in the second example the error is thrown for the same reason. Again, the code needs to run inside a fiber.

---

### The function of yield and run

A fiber must cooperatively give control to another fiber (or the main line of execution). Compare that to the preemptive nature of threads and processes. The giving up control is what is meant by '*yielding* control', and in this case is done by `Fiber.yield()`.

To continue execution (directly after the point of where the fiber yielded), one must call `run()` on the fiber.

The mechanism to pass values in and out of the fiber is through the interplay of yield and run:

- An argument given to `run` (which is outside the fiber), is returned by `yield` (inside the fiber).
- An argument given to `yield` (inside the fiber), is returned by `run` (outside the fiber).

For an example, look at the incremental generator on [the github repository of node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers). Additionally, observe that our Example 1, the callback given to `sample` is essentially ran *outside* the fiber, as it is ran on the next tick (viz. the async nature of `setTimeout`).

Comment: Im sorry if there is a point missing in the question , what I really want to achieve is that how can I get the value from the callback to the outside scope or outside the `Fiber(function(){});`, if the code is executed using `f.run()` ? Because it is the very core of the idea (getting the value from the callback to the outside scope)...

Comment: Ah, I see. But that's a bit of a different question, as the errors you got were due to mistakes in the code. I believe my answer correctly answers your question, but I shall try to rephrase parts of it to better explain the function of yield.

Comment: Is my explanation in any way helpful?

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Andrew, and as hinted in my blog post (see the sentence that follows the example), you have to create a `Fiber` and run it with `run()` to be able to call `Fiber.yield`.

The benefit of fibers is not obvious when you have a single async call to run, but consider the case where you have a function `f1` that calls `f2` that calls `f3`. If `f3` calls a low-level async function with a callback and if you do not use fibers, you have to turn `f3` into an async function with a callback, and then by contagion you also have to turn `f2` and `f1` into async functions. With fibers, you can keep `f1`, `f2` and `f3` as normal functions (without callback). You will need some `Fiber.yield()` magic inside `f3` and you will also need to call `f1` from inside a `Fiber` but you don't need to worry about callbacks in the bodies of `f1` and `f2`.

So fibers really shine when you have multiple layers of code or complex control flow between your high level functions and the low level async functions that they call.

Also, Marcel, who wrote fibers, recommends that you don't use `Fiber.yield()` directly in your code but that you use his *futures* library instead. It's interesting to play with `Fiber.yield` to understand what fibers are made of but I encourage you to use the *futures* library for a real project. It will also help you parallelize your code.